# Problema CSS alineamiento de label inputs - HTML

Tags: html, css

Estoy realizando un formulario de registro, el típico de páginas webs, pero **tengo un problema en cuanto a la disposición de los elementos.**
Mi formulario debe contener los siguientes campos, los cuales se ven en la imagen, pero deben estar en la siguiente distribución:

```
Nombre - Apellidos (deben ocupar la mitad y mitad)
Email (debe ocupar todo el ancho)
DNI Teléfono (deben ocupar la mitad y mitad)
Contraseña1 Contraseña2 (deben ocupar la mitad y mitad)
Registrar (centrado)
¿Ya tienes una cuenta? Ingresa aquí. (centrado)
```

Os dejo el **[image: código HTML y CSS]** que he generado: (estoy sujeto a modificaciones siempre y cuando sea para mejorar y aprender).

```css
*{
     box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body{
     margin: 0;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     background: #204862;
    }
    
    h1{
     color: #fff;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    .form-register{
     width: 85%;
     max-width: 600px;
     margin: auto;
     background: white;
     border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    .form-titulo{
     background: deepskyblue;
     color: #fff;
     padding: 20px;
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: 100;
     font-size: 30px;
     border-top-left-radius: 7px;
     border-top-right-radius: 7px;
     border-bottom: 5px solid red;
    }
    
    .contenedor-inputs{
     padding: 2px 20px;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .input{
     margin-bottom: 8px;
     padding: 8px;
     font-size: 16px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     border: 1px solid darkgray;
    }
    
    .input-2{
     width: 40%;
    }
    
    .input-1{
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    .enviar{
     background: crimson;
     color: #fff;
     margin: auto;
     padding: 10px 40px;
     cursor: pointer;
     font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    .enviar:active{
     transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    
    .form-link{
     width: 100%;
     margin: `px;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 14px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Formulario de registro</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
     </head>
     <body>
      <h1>Formulario de registro</h1>
      <form action="registrar.php" method="POST" class="form-register">
       <h2 class="form-titulo">CREA UNA CUENTA</h2>
       <div class="contenedor-inputs">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" tabindex="1" class="input-2" required>
        <label for="apellidos">Apellidos: </label><input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" tabindex="2" class="input-2" required>
        <br/>
        <label for="email">Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" tabindex="3" class="input-1" required>
        <br/>
        <label for="dni">DNI: </label><input type="text" name="dni" id="dni" placeholder="DNI" tabindex="4" class="input-2" required>
        <label for="telefono">Teléfono: </label><input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" tabindex="5" class="input-2" required>
        <br/>
        <label for="password1">Contraseña: </label><input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" placeholder="Contraseña" tabindex="6" class="input-2" required>
        <label for="password2">Repetir contraseña: </label><input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Repetir contraseña" tabindex="7" class="input-2" required>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="enviar" tabindex="8"/>
        <p class="form-link">¿Ya tienes una cuenta? <a href="#">Ingresa aquí</a></p>
       </div>
      </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Es posible que sea por el margin auto de la clase form-register

Comment: No, el margin: auto; de la clase form-register sirve para que el formulario quede centrado en el TOTAL de la pantalla.

Comment: Probaste usar .cols en divs?

Comment: Sí, pero realmente no quiero una "tabla" con columnas (.cols) desearía un formulario como el que tengo pero "centrado" y alineado. No sé por qué motivo se me descoloca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo podría quedar basándome en tu código

[image: Ejemplo de solución]

**CSS:**

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #204862;
}

h1{
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.form-register{
    width: 85%;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.form-titulo{
    background: deepskyblue;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}

.contenedor-inputs{
    padding: 2px 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.input{
  min-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
  padding-left:5px;
}

.input-2{
    width:35%;
  max-width:150px;
}

.input-1{
    width: 80%;
  max-width: 450px;
}

.enviar{
    background: crimson;
    color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.enviar:active{
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.form-link{
    width: 100%;
    margin: `px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}

/* Contianers */
.container{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Formulario de registro</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Formulario de registro</h1>
        <form action="registrar.php" method="POST" class="form-register">
            <h2 class="form-titulo">CREA UNA CUENTA</h2>
            <div class="contenedor-inputs">
        <div class="container">
                  <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" tabindex="1" class="input input-2" required>
          <label for="apellidos">Apellidos: </label><input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" tabindex="2" class="input input-2" required>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
                  <label for="email">Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" tabindex="3" class="input input-1" required>
                </div>
        <div class="container">
                <label for="dni">DNI: </label><input type="text" name="dni" id="dni" placeholder="DNI" tabindex="4" class="input input-2" required>
                <label for="telefono">Teléfono: </label><input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" tabindex="5" class="input input-2" required>
                </div>
        <div class="container">
                <label for="password1">Contraseña: </label><input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" placeholder="Contraseña" tabindex="6" class="input input-2" required>
                <label for="password2">Repetir contraseña: </label><input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Repetir contraseña" tabindex="7" class="input input-2" required>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="enviar" tabindex="8"/>
                <p class="form-link">¿Ya tienes una cuenta? <a href="#">Ingresa aquí</a></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Te sugiero aprendas a usar Frameworks como Bootstrap ya que esos ayudan mucho a hacer más rápido el trabajo

Answer (score 1):

Introduce cada pareja label-input dentro de un div para que en cada fila solo exista una pareja de elementos:

```
<div class="contenedor-inputs">
    <div>
        <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" tabindex="1" class="input-2" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="apellidos">Apellidos: </label><input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" tabindex="2" class="input-2" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" tabindex="3" class="input-1" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="dni">DNI: </label><input type="text" name="dni" id="dni" placeholder="DNI" tabindex="4" class="input-2" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="telefono">Teléfono: </label><input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" tabindex="5" class="input-2" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password1">Contraseña: </label><input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" placeholder="Contraseña" tabindex="6" class="input-2" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password2">Repetir contraseña: </label><input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Repetir contraseña" tabindex="7" class="input-2" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="enviar" tabindex="8"/>
        <p class="form-link">¿Ya tienes una cuenta? <a href="#">Ingresa aquí</a></p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

De esta forma solo te quedaría centrar el contenido de estos divs usando una clase con los estilos necesarios.